# Get QGIS to understand dimensions in 3D raster

Tags: qgis, raster, 3d, netcdf, hdf5

I want to open 3D raster data in a NetCDF file in QGIS 3.10.4 in Linux.

I have a 3D matrix of dims (10000,5000,10) in a NetCDF-formated file. The first two dimensions correspond to longitude and latitude, the third is viewing angle (but irrelevant for the question).

I use the command line tool gdalinfo on the file, and I extract the sub-dataset of interest, for example:

HDF5:"path_to_file/filename"://VARIABLE

Then I use in QGIS: `Layer-> Add Layer -> Add raster layer`. Then I select Source type=File, and I paste the line above in the Source field.

The dataset shows in the Layers browser and in the screen, but I get a 10000-height x 10-width image, with 5000 bands!

How can I instruct QGIS to show me 10000x5000 images?